# How to filter out from count distinct query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to calculate numbers of customers whom are active in the past 3 and 6 months.

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT CustomerNo)
FROM SalesDetail
WHERE InvoiceDate > (GETDATE() - 180) AND InvoiceDate < (GETDATE() - 90)

SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT CustomerNo)
FROM SalesDetail
WHERE InvoiceDate > (GETDATE() - 90)
```

However, based on above query, I'll get count Customers which has been active for both in the last 3 months and the last 6 months, even if there are duplicates like this.

- Customer A bought once in past 3 months
- Customer A bought once in past 6 months too

How do I filter out the customers, so that if customer A has been active in both past 3 and 6 months, he/she will only be counted in the 'active in past 3 months' query and not in the 'active in past 6 months' too.

Comment: Can you please share some output data for a better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem this way
Let us consider you have following table. You might have more columns but for the result you want, we only require **customer_id** and **date** they bought something on.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[customer_invoice](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [customer_id] [int] NULL,
    [date] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_customer_invoice] PRIMARY KEY([id]);
```

I created this sample data on this table

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[customer_invoice]
   ([customer_id]
   ,[date])
 VALUES
   (1,convert(date,'2019-12-01')),
   (2,convert(date,'2019-11-05')),
   (2,convert(date,'2019-8-01')),
   (3,convert(date,'2019-7-01')),
   (4,convert(date,'2019-4-01'));
```

Lets not try to jump directly on the final solution directly but take a single leap each time.

```
SELECT customer_id, MIN(DATEDIFF(DAY,date,GETDATE())) AS lastActiveDays
FROM customer_invoice GROUP BY customer_id;
```

The above query gives you the number of days before each customer was active

```
customer_id lastActiveDays
   1         15
   2         41
   3         168
   4         259
```

Now We will use this query as subquery and Add a new column **ActiveWithinCategory** so that in later step we can group our data by the column.

```
SELECT customer_id, lastActiveDays,
    CASE WHEN lastActiveDays<90 THEN 'active within 3 months'
         WHEN lastActiveDays<180 THEN 'active within 6 months'
         ELSE 'not active' END AS ActiveWithinCategory 
FROM(
    SELECT customer_id, MIN(DATEDIFF(DAY,date,GETDATE())) AS lastActiveDays
    FROM customer_invoice GROUP BY customer_id
)AS temptable;
```

This query gives you the the following result

```
customer_id lastActiveDays  ActiveWithinCategory
   1              15        active within 3 months
   2              41        active within 3 months
   3             168        active within 6 months
   4             259        not active
```

Now use the above whole thing as subquery and Group the data using **ActiveWithinCategory**

```
SELECT ActiveWithinCategory, COUNT(*) AS NumberofCustomers FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, lastActiveDays,
        CASE WHEN lastActiveDays<90 THEN 'active within 3 months'
             WHEN lastActiveDays<180 THEN 'active within 6 months'
             ELSE 'not active' END AS ActiveWithinCategory 
    FROM(
        SELECT customer_id, MIN(DATEDIFF(DAY,date,GETDATE())) AS lastActiveDays
        FROM customer_invoice GROUP BY customer_id
    )AS temptable 
) AS FinalResult GROUP BY ActiveWithinCategory;
```

And Here is your final result

```
ActiveWithinCategory    NumberofEmployee
active within 3 months      2
active within 6 months      1
not active                  1
```

If you want to achieve same thing is MySQL Database
Here is the final Query

```
SELECT ActiveWithinCategory, count(*) NumberofCustomers FROM(
    SELECT MIN(DATEDIFF(curdate(),date)) AS lastActiveBefore,
           IF(MIN(DATEDIFF(curdate(),date))<90,
              'active within 3 months',
              IF(MIN(DATEDIFF(curdate(),date))<180,'active within 6 months','not active')
            ) ActiveWithinCategory
    FROM customer_invoice GROUP BY customer_id
) AS FinalResult GROUP BY ActiveWithinCategory;
```

Comment: Yes, this is the exact solution that i'm trying to solve. thank you very much for your help Sir.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want to do conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    CustomerNo,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN InvoiceDate > GETDATE() - 90 THEN 1 END) AS cnt_last_3,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN InvoiceDate > GETDATE() - 180 AND InvoiceDate < GETDATE() - 90
               THEN 1 END) AS cnt_first_3
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    CustomerNo;
```

Here `cnt_last_3` is the count over the immediate past 3 months, and `cnt_first_3` is the count from the 3 month period starting 6 months ago and ending 3 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the distinct count you may add distinct like this

```
Select 
 count( Case when dt between getdate()- 90 and getdate()  then id else null end) cnt_3_months
,count(distinct Case when dt between getdate() - 180 and getdate() - 90 then id  else null end) cnt_6_months
from a
```